# In-application Java command line

Tags: java, bash, shell, command-line, lua

I've been trying to figure out how to make a sort of command line within Java that acts similar to [ComputerCraft's](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/892282-132-computercraft-143-now-with-printed-books/) CraftOS interface using known libraries like jBASH and luaj, except it seems that anything I come across either isn't maintained anymore or doesn't function all too well.  Unfortunately, dan200 keeps his source under lock and key, so I can't even see how he did it...

Does this mean I might end up having to create my own BASH-y shell and/or my own LUA-y scripting method, or is there something that's being maintained now that is at least somewhat usable?

Comment: I may have missed the point, but is there anything stopping you from just running bash from java and piping its standard streams to your ui?

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up my comment with some code;

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash");
InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();
OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();
```

And you would probably wrap those in `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` respectively, so that you can use them as character streams, allowing you to do things like read and write lines of text. Eg;

```
BufferedReader stdoutReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, that's not what the OP is trying to do. (S)he's not trying to give users access to some system shell; rather, (s)he's trying to create a shell-like interface to control aspects of, or take actions within, the program.

Comment: You might well be right, I shall delete this if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

[BeanShell is a small, free, embeddable Java source interpreter with object scripting language features, written in Java. BeanShell dynamically executes standard Java syntax and extends it with common scripting conveniences such as loose types, commands, and method closures like those in Perl and JavaScript.](http://www.beanshell.org/)

Answer (score 1):

> […] known libraries like jBASH and luaj, except it seems that anything I come across either isn't maintained anymore or doesn't function all too well.

Luaj is highly-rated on Sourceforge; it was last updated a year ago; and the lack of updates since then might just mean that it hasn't really *needed* updates. Lua's a pretty simple language.

Even if you find that luaj isn't 100% perfect for you, I imagine that modifying it would be much easier than "having to create my own BASH-y shell and/or my own LUA-y scripting method". (The latter probably wouldn't give 100% perfect results, either, unless you already have experience implementing scripting languages.)